# Error when return custom class array from WEB API call

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest

When I am returning array of Person class from WebAPI, I am getting following error when I call that WebAPI., Please help me how would I resolve the problem.
WebAPI CODE

```
public class PersonController : ApiController
{
    public Person[] Get()
    {
        Person[] p = new Person[3]
        { 
            new Person("ABC", "XYZ", 1),
            new  Person("A", "B", 1),
            new Person("D", "E", 1)
         };

         return p;
   }
```

Person Class:

```
public class Person
{
    public String FirstName;
    public String LastName;
    public int PersonID;

    public Person(string fName, string lName, int id)
    {
        this.FirstName = fName;
        this.LastName = lName;
        this.PersonID = id;
    }
}
```

This is the error i am getting:

> An error has occurred. 
>   The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'. 
>   System.InvalidOperationException
>     An error has
>   occurred.  Type
>   'ConsoleApplication1.Person' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it
>   with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its
>   members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If
>   the type is a collection, consider marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported types. 
>   
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException
>     at ...

Comment: public class Person
    {
        public String FirstName;
        public String LastName;
        public int PersonID;

        public Person(string fName, string lName, int id)
        {
            this.FirstName = fName;
            this.LastName = lName;
            this.PersonID = id;
        }
    }

Comment: @AnisNoorAli Change it from public fields to public properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just because your `Person` class doesn't have a default constructor. To resolve this issue just add a default constructor to your class:

```
public class Person
{
    public String FirstName;
    public String LastName;
    public int PersonID;

    public Person() {}

    public Person(string fName, string lName, int id)
    {
        this.FirstName = fName;
        this.LastName = lName;
        this.PersonID = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I don't understand why it's require default constructor when I return array of person.. It's work perfect when i return only person object instead of array and without default constructor... Please Arin describe the reason, I will appreciate your reply. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you a lot.

> Type 'ConsoleApplication1.Person' cannot be serialized

The problem is in how you structured your `Person` model. ASP.NET Web API can automatically serialize a model, and include it in the body of the message so that the client can deserialize the object and read the data.

To make your model serializable, you need to have public getters and setters for the properties you want to transmit. Here is an example to get you started:

```
public class Person
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public Person(string fName, string lName, int id)
    {
        this.FirstName = fName;
        this.LastName = lName;
        this.PersonID = id;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization) site has some great information on ways you can manipulate your models to accomplish different things.

Comment: I don't think so Setter and getter make this correct.. When I am returning just person obj instead of array it's work fine..